# turn list of categorical variables into (0,1) list

Tags: python, numpy, data-conversion

my problem: I have a list of categorical variables such as

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['A','A','B','B','C','C','C'])
unique_vars = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(np.unique(a))}
c = np.array([unique_vars[i] for i in a])
```

which yields:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

and I want to turn into:

```
res = [0,0, 1,1, 0,0,0]
```

in essence, at every "switch", the number has to be switched from 1 to 0.

Comment: Do you... have rules for converting them..?

Comment: `res = [e if e == 1 else 0 for e in l]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, you can get the `unique IDs` in a vectorized manner with [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and additional input argument `return_inverse` -

```
c = np.unique(a,return_inverse=1)[1]
```

Then, use `modulus(..,2)` to make the switches between `0` and `1` -

```
out = np.mod(c, 2)  # Or c%2
```

Comment: ISTM this will only work if `a` is sorted, which is true for the OP's example.  Do we know it'll be true in general?

Comment: awesome! eaxactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking something like this:

```
arr = ['A','A','B','B','C','C','C']

def get_switched_array(in_array, value):
    return [ 1 if v == value else 0 for v in in_array ]

print get_switched_array( arr, 'A')
print get_switched_array( arr, 'B')
print get_switched_array( arr, 'C')
```

which outputs:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```